# Установка VestaCP на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, vesta

Пытаюсь установить VestaCP на чистую Ubuntu Server 18.04.

```
root@test:~/VestaCP# ./vst-install.sh
--2018-05-28 21:24:14--  http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install-ubuntu.sh
Распознаётся vestacp.com (vestacp.com)… 104.236.66.100
Подключение к vestacp.com (vestacp.com)|104.236.66.100|:80... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа… 200 OK
Длина: нет данных [text/plain]
Сохранение в: «vst-install-ubuntu.sh»

vst-install-ubuntu.sh                       [  <=>    ]  46,01K   175KB/s    за 0,3s

2018-05-28 21:24:15 (175 KB/s) - «vst-install-ubuntu.sh» сохранён [47114]

Error: No access to Vesta repository
root@test:~/VestaCP#
```

Как я понимаю, поддержки этой версии ещё нет. Что-то можно с этим сделать, или лучше поставить Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Comment: У меня при переходе на http://apt.vestacp.com/xenial/ выдаётся `403`, а при переходе по http://apt.vestacp.com/bionic/ - 404. Так что видимо да, бобёр ещё не готов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент последняя поддерживаемая версия 17.04. Актуальную информацию можно всегда найти тут:
http://vestacp.com/install/